# Static imports inside scala REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Given the following object:

```
scala> object P2pClient {
     |   type Num = Double
     |   type Weights = Array[Array[Num]]
     | }
defined object P2pClient
```

and the following import:

```
import P2pClient._
```

The `Weights` type *seems* to be properly understood:

```
val w: Weights = new Weights(3)
w: P2pClient.Weights = Array(null, null, null)
```

But then why is it *not* working in the following construct:

```
case class SendWeightsReq(W: Weights) extends P2pReq[Weights] {
     |   override def value() = W
     | }
<console>:12: error: not found: type Weights
       case class SendWeightsReq(W: Weights) extends P2pReq[Weights] {
                                                            ^
<console>:12: error: not found: type Weights
       case class SendWeightsReq(W: Weights) extends P2pReq[Weights] {
                                    ^
```

Any ideas on what were happening here (/workaround) ?

**Update**  There appear to be significant limitations on wildcard imports int he REPL. Here is another simpler illustration:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> trait TT {  def x[T <: java.io.Serializable : TypeTag]: T }
<console>:10: error: not found: type TypeTag
       trait TT {  def x[T <: java.io.Serializable : TypeTag]: T }
                                                     ^
```

So we see that the wildcard import did *not* work. Here is the same code with the explicit package:

```
scala> trait TT {  def x[T <: java.io.Serializable : reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag]: T }
defined trait TT
```

Comment: Use trailing `// show` to print what is compiled, including imports. Note space between slash and show.

Comment: @som-snytt  Having trouble with that.  I put `// show` after the code above as your mentioned. When doing a `:paste`  and then `ctrl-D` the REPL is automatically placing `:quit` - killing the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the issue is due to my using the **Spark** REPL `spark-shell`. The issue is not happening in the normal Scala REPL.

Comment: Spark does things differently and had a bug. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9740

Answer (score 2):

Good news: your code works! Bad news: I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Here is my REPL session; I was going to build up to your example and see what broke, but nothing did.

```
scala> object P2pClient { type Num = Int; type Weights = Array[Array[Num]] }
defined object P2pClient

scala> import P2pClient._
import P2pClient._

scala> val x = new Weights(3)
x: Array[Array[P2pClient.Num]] = Array(null, null, null)

scala> case class SendWeights(W: Weights)
defined class SendWeights

scala> val s = new SendWeights(new Weights(3))
s: SendWeights = SendWeights([[I@1cab0bfb)
```

Hmmm. Trivial example works.

```
scala> case class SendWeights2(w: Weights) { def dubs = w }
defined class SendWeights2
```

Works when it has a body.

```
scala> trait P2pReq[+T] { def value(): Unit }
defined trait P2pReq

scala> case class SendWeights3(W: Weights) extends P2pReq[Weights] {
override def value() = W }
defined class SendWeights3

scala> val foo = new SendWeights3(new Weights(3))
foo: SendWeights3 = SendWeights3([[I@51dcb805)
res2: P2pClient.Weights = Array(null, null, null)
```

Aaaaand works when it extends a polymorphic trait and overrides one of its members. The only thing that may be different is your definition of `P2pReq`, but I don't see how that could cause one of your types to go unrecognized by the interpreter.

Comment: Huh.  Well i'll upvote your answer (it is helpful) but hold off on awarding - to see if anyone else experiences my case  - or understands what may be different.

Comment: I added my own answer - it happens in Spark repl not just scala repl. But I will award to you for pointing the correct direction.

Comment: I appreciate it, and I'm glad I could help, but I think you should accept your own answer, as it is the correct one!

Comment: OK - i think you were right. But did not want to disappoint you.  Anyways I can not accept my own answer for another two days. So enjoy it for now ;)   In any case your answer did help me to get to the solution - so the upvote is fully warranted.